# Variável de classe no Java têm o mesmo comportamento que em Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby

Em Ruby uma variável de classe que é modificada por um objeto acaba modificando o valor de todos os outros objetos ao invés de fazer uma cópia desse valor. Isso também ocorre em Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Java, as variáveis de classes são declaradas com `static`. Neste caso, o objeto a qual essa variável se refere, será o mesmo para todas as instâncias da classe. Efetivamente, variáveis declaradas com `static` em Java são globais.